# How to not round results within sql calculations with count

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL keeps rounding the results of my calculations and I do not seem to find an article on how to fix this.

I am trying to do calculations within SQL. This to BI self service easier.

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CONTRACTID) / (SELECT COUNT(RENTALOBJECTID) FROM PMCCONTRACTOBJECT) AS result 
FROM PMCCONTRACT
```

The result I am getting is 3 while I expect to get 3.2973.

Wow sorry, i added the wrong code. 
Should make more sense now

Comment: What is the datatype of "YOURCOLUMN"?

Comment: DECIMAL(10,2) implies a precision of 8 and a scale of 2. If you need a scale of 4 as per your example you may need to use DECIMAL(10,4) where the precision would be 6 and scale would be 4

Comment: Not enough information to reproduce your issue.   You have almost certainly oversimplified it and obfuscated the actual problem.   For instance, your sample code has nothing to do with COUNT, even though it is in the subject of your question.

Comment: As Tab pointed out this is difficult to diagnose without more information, but if the issue deals with `COUNT` then you likely need to `CAST` the count as a decimal before any division as `COUNT` returns an `INT` datatype.

Answer (score 1):

since you are getting 3, you possibly allowed an integer division when you didn't mean to - always cast to float or suitable Decimal before dividing - or use suitable data types in your calculation

see the following example as an illustration of what happens

```
 select 10/3, cast(10 as float) / cast(3 as float)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i gave little information i was able to find the awnser

```
    SELECT cast (count(CONTRACTID) as decimal) / (SELECT count(RENTALOBJECTID) 
FROM PMCCONTRACTOBJECT) AS result FROM PMCCONTRACT
```